# Best Practices for 3 Tier Development

Tags: .net, asp.net, architecture

Does anyone know of any documentation by MS or someone else that lays out the best practices for developing a 3 tier architecture in ASP.NET.  I am in the process of trying to convince my boss that the current architecture needs rethought and reworked to provide a flexible and reusable system.  I have found a lot of generic documentation that tells you at a high level the best practices as far as how to do this but little showing how you actually implement them.  I need to show him documentation as far as the advantages to using business objects versus data sets and things to that level of detail.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have looked at the guides but what I am looking for is some examples of them being applied.  Ideally I would like an open source project that I can look at that used the guides as a base.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft's [Patterns & Practices group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx) has published various whitepapers and documents in the form of "architectural guidance" that can be helpful. They recently published a number of ["pocket guides"](http://www.codeplex.com/AppArch/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Pocket%20Guides&referringTitle=Home) as well. Even if you don't follow them to the letter, they're likely to be a great starting point for discussing your particular needs.

That they come from Microsoft may also help add credibility in the discussion with your boss. There's one on [Web Application Architecture](http://www.codeplex.com/AppArch/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=19802), in particular, that sounds like it may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend looking into [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/).  It's a far better option for n-tier appliactions as it allows for a greater degree of Seperation Of Concerns.  This leads to a more testable and maintanable application that can be achieved with ASP.NET